# Alternative to meshgrid matlab

Tags: matlab, mesh

I would like to reduce the dimension of the matrices that I obtain using `meshgrid` because I'm interested in a thick mesh in the center of the matrix because is where I have many variations of my variable, while a wider mesh going far from the center.
The thing that I want to underline is that I DON'T want a finite method kind of function, but just a function that works like `meshgrid` generating the two matrices like meshgrid but with different steps. I know that I could implement a finite element method or something else, but what I want to do is just reduce as much as possible the computations needed to generate the matrices and have a faster code.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how meshgrid isn't the fit here for this. If I understand you I simply concatenated three vectors for instance on some interval with one denser than the other and I get the following for this little function.

```
x1 = linspace(0,5,10);
x2 = linspace(5,10,100);
x3 = linspace(10,15,10);
x = [x1,x2,x3];
y = x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;
mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]